# Rest spring upload file with parameter in form

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, jax-rs

I am trying to upload a file i can able to upload a file but i need to post one parameter present in the form, now i need to post one parameter and upload file in the form.

I tried Multi part and Form url encoded in the consumes annotation. It is not working i am getting an error.

I used @FormDataParam and @FormParam annotation in the method.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider$FormDataParamValueFactory.provide(FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.java:203)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:81)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.SubResourceLocatorRouter.getResource(SubResourceLocatorRouter.java:220)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.SubResourceLocatorRouter.apply(SubResourceLocatorRouter.java:133)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:128)
```

Comment: I used the FormDataParam to get the parameter it is working, but still i am getting this exception, because of this i am getting 404 exception in console (chrome).

Answer (score 0):

Server side:

```
@POST
@Path("import")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=UTF-8")
public void uploadScenario(@FormDataParam("importScenario") final InputStream is,
            @FormDataParam("complectId") final Long complectId) {
    // Realisation
}
```

Client side:

```
<form id="importForm" target="my_iframe" action="rest/exportimport/import" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="uploader" type="file" name="importScenario" size="50"><input type="submit">
    <input type="text" style="display:none" name="complectId" value="'+id+'">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response i am done this one already. But the problem i have now is the exception i posted.